# Assigning a value to an input form field using javascript is clearing after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a domain name and set it as a cookie. Then the cookie is retrieved again and its value is assigned to the value of an HTML input field. This code is used in a Shopify store.

Everything works fine except that the value of the input field (id="promoter") is cleared after the page has loaded. In other words, I see the value for a fraction of a second in the form field but then when the page is fully loaded the value is cleared and the field becomes empty. What am I doing wrong? If I assign a default value to the input field then the value persists and it's not cleared.

Could it be that Shopify clears all values of input fields when using javascript? Please help!

```
function setCookie(name) {
let value = window.location.host.split(".")[0];
let days = 3;
let expires = "";
if (days) {
let date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
let nameEQ = name + "=";
let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
let c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
}
return null;
}

function checkCookie(name) {
let user = getCookie(name);
if (user != "") {
CartAttribute("promoter", user);  
}
}
function CartAttribute(name, user){
document.getElementById(name).value = user;
}
window.onload = function() {
setCookie("promoter");
getCookie("promoter");
checkCookie("promoter");
};
```

ON THE CART PAGE

```
<input id="promoter" type="text" name="attributes[promoter]" >
```